# unique binary string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have a xlsx file that looks something like this table:

```
name                 place               link 
terry mike           12<longbeach>       http://www.google.com/xyz
jessica mike         12<longbeach>       http://www.google.com/abc
amanda albert        189<washington>     http://www.amazone.com/cali
terry mike           189<longbeach>      http://www.google.com/nnn
```

i used Pandas in python to import as a dataframe and was able to count each column unique string by using :

```
len(df.Name.unique())
```

so for name i got ***3*** which is correct : terry mike,jessica mike,amanda albert

**question** how to convert these 3 cloumns into a binary unique string using pandas dataframe so that for the Name column output be like this:

```
Name    place   link
001     001     001
010     001     010
011     010     011
001     011     100
```

so that each cell is unique i know how many different strings i have from  each column by `len(df.Name.unique())`in this case for **name its 3** for **place its 3** and **link is 4**

is there a simple way to do it with pandas

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to anonymize the data? Do you care if terry mike gets really gets '001' or would '2' or '010' work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
factors, idx = pd.factorize(df.name)
width = int(np.log2(factors.max()) // 1 + 1)

pd.Series(factors, df.index).apply(np.binary_repr, width=width)

0    00
1    01
2    10
3    00
dtype: object
```

Comment: Tried your method works great thanks for your support piRSquared

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really care about whether 'Terry mike' gets '001', you could use the `category` dtype:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes)

   name  place  link 
0     2      0      3
1     1      0      1
2     0      2      0
3     2      1      2
```

If you want binary with 3 digits:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes).applymap('{0:03b}'.format)

  name place link 
0  010   000   011
1  001   000   001
2  000   010   000
3  010   001   010
```

Comment: i tried using category dtype as suggested but am not familier with it i get this error   " TypeError: ('data type "category" not understood', u'occurred at index Name')  " am not sure what need to be changed with column name or df as in Dataframe name ?  Thank you Julien

Comment: I've tested the above and it works using Python 3.5 and Pandas 0.19.1. What's your pandas version? (`pd.__version__`)

Comment: the pandas version am using is 0.14.1 i will try to update it thanks

Comment: Yes please do that. And then you should probably accept one of the two answers so we can mark this thread as resolved. Thanks